# Show random div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem,

**in Html**

```
<div class="item ">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
<div class="item">Four</div>
```

**in JS**

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length);
$('.item').hide().eq(random).show();
```

I need add class **(no-active)** of automatically and randomly in the div with class **(item)**, but no for all divs. only some div.

Now my code only show 1 div, and it's not what I want.

Comment: *"now just a add the class in 1 div."*: your code does not add a class. It only shows/hides. Please clarify your question.

Comment: That's why I said, "I need a class (no-active) to be added automatically and randomly"

Comment: So, did you read the documentation on `addClass`? What is the problem?

Comment: Add class automatically and randomly in the div with class (item), but no for all divs. only some div

Comment: But you already have the automatic and random part working, so I don't understand what the problem is? I think this question should be closed. Or, you should be much clearer about desired effect, and why your current code is not good in your opinion. Also explain what `show` `hide` has to do with your question. Is there a connection between being visible and having the no-active class?

Comment: I think my question is very clear, I need to add the class (no-active)  to be added automatically and randomly in the div with class (item). but no for all divs. only some div., Now my code only hides all the div and only leaves 1.. and it's not how I want it to work

Comment: So you don't want to use `show` / `hide`: apparently it has nothing to do with what you really want: add/remove class `no-active`. Then use a loop to calculate a random decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` and `toggleClass` for that:

```js
$(".item").each(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('no-active', Math.random() < 0.5);
});
```

```css
.no-active { visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item ">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
<div class="item">Four</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! @trincot

Answer (score 2):

you try this :

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length);
var newrandom = 0;
//alert(random);
if(random==0){//alert(random);
$('.item').hide().eq(random).show();
}else if(random>0){
    $('.item').hide();
  for(var i=1; i<=random; i++){

    newrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length);
        $('.item').eq(newrandom).show();
  //alert(newrandom);
   }

 }
```

Using this u will get random no. for random times.